# How to express path to a class method?

Tags: oop, terminology

I need to communicate that `function bar of class MyNamespace\Foo` needs some modifications. I'm using an imperative OOP language with syntax similar to Java. Is there a shorter way to say this? `MyNamespace\Foo\bar()` looks close enough but not sure if that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is usually used in PHP: `MyNamespace\Foo::bar()`

---

Edit: Reply to comment

Since static methods can be called dynamically, you could use `MyNamespace\Foo->bar()` to cover for both cases. However, standard usage I've always seen across all documentation, and usage that IDEs can generally recognize in docblocks when you ctrl+click through them all seem to be with double-colon, as originally noted.

I haven't seen Doctrine's approach in many cases.

Comment: I think that's a little ambiguous considering that's how static methods are accessed... but I don't know of any alternatives.

Comment: Doctrine uses the `MyNamespace\Foo::bar()` for static methods, while `MyNamespace\Foo#baz()` for instance methods. Same applies to properties. Also note that you don't need to prepend `\\` in a string.

Answer (score 2):

If it's similar to Java why not using the dot notation: `myNamespace.Foo.bar()`?

Comment: The one big reason i can come up with, is that it doesn't distinguish between top-level package members and inner classes.  I never did very much like that Java makes the two look the same, giving you 2^depth places to look for the definition of a class.  :P  If i were coming up with a notation, i might instead use `::` to denote an inner class and `.` for top-level members and subpackages.

Comment: Hm, I don't know if I understand you right. Typically package names are all starting lower case, class names are all starting upper case. So a second name part starting with an upper case letter is a sub-class. If that doesn't suit you you could use the stacktrace notation, where sub-classes are separated from the class name with a dollar sign.

Comment: "Typically" isn't good enough.  The uppercase vs lowercase thing is merely an easily ignored convention.  There's nothing preventing me from making a package named `com.plbth.Foo` or a class `com.plbth.ehh.foo`.  You have a point about `$`, though.  It'd get hideous with a lot of nesting, but that much nesting is a symptom of deeper issues anyway...